# Where are the SquirrelMail Logs?

Tags: linux, email, unix, computer-building, open-source

I am having problems sending mail using SquirrelMail.  I asked the open source support for help and here is their response.

> What you need to do is look in your logs and show the error that is
> preventing this.  That's the only way to hone in quickly on your problem,
> especially when asking from help from other people.

Which logs? I looked in the httpd logs but I think that's incorrect because that is the web server log if I'm correct?

But where do I find the SquirrelMail logs? I've searched hours and can't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

SquirrelMail is a PHP application, so its logging behaviour is configured in `php.ini`. Usually this file lies somewhere like `/etc/php/php.ini`. In my case it lies in `/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini`. I configured it like this:

```
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_log = /dev/stderr
```

This will cause error messages to be printed out by the Apache process (which in my case is running in a Docker container), but it will not show errors in the browser.

Unfortunately, it seems that SquirrelMail is deliberately suppressing error messages using the `@` operator, which makes it impossible to tell what is going on. In my case, I got an error `Error connecting to IMAP server`. What I had to to to find out more details was to search for this error in the SquirrelMail source code, find a function call above it that was prefixed with a `@`, remove the `@` and then restart my webserver. Then error messages were finally showing up in the log. The line that I had to change looked like this:

```php
$imap_stream = @fsockopen($imap_server_address, $imap_port, $error_number, $error_string, 15);
```

But depending which error you encounter, you will have to change the source code in a different place.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably an XY problem, where:

**Y: Where are the SquirrelMail logs?**

SquirrelMail is an *email client*, formally *mail user agent* (MUA) written in PHP.  It doesn't send or receive email, but acts as an IMAP (and SMTP) client. As a PHP *web application* it doesn't have own logging, so the information is in the web server logs, usually separated as *access* and *error* logs.

**X: How can I debug my mail delivery?**

This depends on which *mail servers* you are using. Slightly simplified, mail servers have two sides (e.g. Wikipedia article on [Email agent (infrastructure)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_agent_(infrastructure)) helps with perceiving the overall picture):

- *message transfer agents* (MTA) & *message submission agents* (MSA) builds a network for delivering the mail using the SMTP protocol.
- *message delivery agent* (MDA) that delivers the mail to local mailboxes, stores them and allows accessing the mailbox using protocols like the IMAP used in SquirrelMail or Microsoft's MAPI.

Some mail server software have everything bundled and some are specialized to provide e.g. only MTA or MDA services. This means in order to debug email delivery, you have to:

1. Check your SquirrelMail configuration and see which servers it connects to.
2. Rule out it's not these client-server connections that are failing.
3. If the problem is with sending mail, concentrate on the SMTP server, if with receiving mail, concentrate on the IMAP server.
4. Figure out which server software were used.
5. Look for the problems in their logs.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am trying to do 5 as you suggested.  I see the /var/log/httpd/domainname.com-access.log and error.log.  That is where I will get the information as to what the problem is.  Now the problem is I am trying to see the contents of the logs I would figure "cat domainname.com-error.log" would work but it doesn't.  I am user su.  

The permissions for directory httpd is `drwxr--r--.`
The permissions for domainname.com-access.log is -rw-r--r--

Comment: I added execute privileges to jessemacdougall.ninja-access.log via "chmod 724". Now file has octal notation of "-rwx-w-r--" which means I should be able to "cat" the file or "tail" to see the contents.  Nope.  No dice...

Comment: Permissions alone don't tell anything, as they are for user, group and others: you'd have to know the user and the group, too. https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_file_permissions You could read the log files as root, or if the group for a log file is `adm`, as a member of the `adm` group.

Comment: Thanks.  So I changed the file to chmod 777 -rwxrwxrwx surely I can see the contents of the file.  Nope.

Comment: Looks like both of the logs are empty! But how? I am trying to send an email using squirrelmail which was working fine.  So if the log is empty how do I determine what the root of the problem is?